# SQLite / Javascript: How to know when all values in column A are identical

Tags: javascript, mysql, sqlite

As part of a drill down text search of thousands of rows, many of which contain the same data in Column A, I'd like to know when all of the rows in the sqlite result set for Column A are the same. eg. If the search term is 'ai' and all of the rows in the result set for Column A = 'in pain' do this function.

So how do I programatically, either in sqlite or using javascript on the result set ask: if all the rows in Column A are identical?

It's probably something simple (hopefully), but it just isn't coming to me today...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Javascript in the success function of the db call:

```
var detailsarr=[];
if (results.rows && results.rows.length) {
for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
var details=results.rows.item(i).details;
if(detailsarr.toString().indexOf(details)===-1){detailsarr.push('"'+details+'"');}
    }
detailsarr = '['+detailsarr+']';
var detailsdata=JSON.parse(detailsarr);
if(detailsdata[1]){THEN ALL ROWS ARE NOT IDENTICAL}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT columnA, count(*) 
FROM  MyTable 
WHERE myField like '%AI%'  
GROUP BY columnA
```

Probably won't be the fastest as it's doing a % on both sides... Here's a [SQLLite article](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

You could use Regular expression search for AI on field which would likely be faster

Updated but I still don't think I fully understand the question sample data would help.. so

COLUMNA
in pain
in pain
in the lair
in the lair

Do you want to see

```
in pain      2
in the lair  2
```

or do you want to see
`no records found` (since all the values in columnA containing ai didn't match?)

---maybe this is what you're after...

```
select count(*) mcount from (
    SELECT columnA, count(*) 
    FROM  MyTable 
    WHERE columnA like '%AI%'  
    GROUP BY columnA) innerResult
```

If mcount > 1 then columnA has more than 1 value matching '%AI%'

Comment: That selects the rows that match %ai%, but it doesn't tell me if all the rows in Column A are the same 'in pain' maybe there's a row in there with 'in the lair'. I need to know when all the rows contain the same thing in Column A.

Comment: @K'shin updated response but need direction on if you want to see all the ai's and their counts, or no records found or .. what?

Comment: I expect there to be multiple rows containing 'ai', the question is do all those rows have the same value in Column A, or not? True or False is enough for this question, but to see how many records of each distinct row would be handy for other things ;-)

Comment: Then I think my 2nd query answers both needs.  the outer query is true/false esque in that it if its > 1 it's false = 1 True = 0 then nothing = AI.  The inner select answers the handy for other things..

Comment: Thanks xQbert. That is a pretty cool query, and it does tell me about the rows in the column matching the term, unfortunately, it is run on the database and creates it's own result set. Separate from the result set we're showing to the user that also has a lot of other things to check before spitting out the result set. As per the original question above I'd love to be able to run some code that examines an existing SQLite result set to see if all the rows in column A (in the result set, not in the db) are the same. I suspect this will have to be done in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This would be expensive to do in SQL:

```
 SELECT ColumnA, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable WHERE ColumnA LIKE '%ai%' AND ColumnA <> outer.ColumnA) AS OtherCount
   FROM YourTable AS outer WHERE ColumnA LIKE '%ai%';
```

In javascript, you'll just iterate over the rows maintaining a dictionary of column A values and when you have two keys in the dictionary you know that not all the results are the same.

Comment: Thanks Larry, can you show the javascript to check the dictionary (dictionary = dictionary + newrow;) for >= 2 keys too please?